# Error: Number of query values and destination fields are not the same

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb

```
Public Class RoomInfo

    Dim ValTx As String
    Dim ValNr As Integer

Private Sub cboRoomType_DropDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboRoomType.DropDown
        cboRoomType.Items.Clear()
        qry = "select RoomType from tblRoomType"
        cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(qry, con)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        While dr.Read
            cboRoomType.Items.Add(dr("RoomType"))
        End While
    End Sub
    Private Sub cboRoomType_SelectValueChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboRoomType.SelectedValueChanged
        ValTx = cboRoomType.Text
        qry = "select RoomType from tblRoomType where RoomType = '" & ValTx & "'"

        cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(qry, con)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        If dr.Read Then
            ValTx = dr("RoomType")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnNext_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
        qry = "Insert into tblCheckIn (Guest_ID, GRoomType, GRoomNo, GRoomID, GRoomAmount, CheckInDate, Days, ChecOutDate) values ('" &
            txtGuestID.Text & "','" &
            ValTx &
            txtRoomNo.Text & "','" &
            txtRoomId.Text & "','" &
            txtRAmount.Text & "','" &
            dtpCheckIn.Value &
            txtDays.Text & "','" &
            dtpCheckOut.Value & "')"

        cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(qry, con)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        MsgBox("Successfully added in the database")
    End Sub
```

I dont know what the problem is here. I guess it's the combobox, the selected value in combo box should be added in database. What is the right correct value for that combobox? Can someone help me?

Comment: The person who kindly provided [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29056505/2144390) to your previous question showed you **(1)** how to use `Parameter` statements in your code, and **(2)** that when you run INSERT (or UPDATE, or DELETE) statements you do *not* use `.ExecuteReader()`. You really should make *SOME* effort to learn from what the nice people here are telling you.

Comment: `ValTx &` you need to add a **comma** here: `ValTx & ", " &`

Answer (score 1):

It is telling you that you have specified a different number of column to insert into (8) than the number of values to insert (6). This is because you have concatenated 2 of the values into 2 field I believe, just count them and you will see what I mean.